# How to Deploy Django on apache2 server using native python installation ?

Tags: python, django, apache

I have developed an Django application which uses a python binding for  c/C++ based dependency. Now  How can I deploy this application without virtualenv using native python installation.

My "000-default.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    Alias /static /home/jai/myproject/protocol/static
    <Directory /home/jai/myproject/protocol/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>



    <Directory /home/jai/myproject/pep_learn>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory> 


    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/jai/myproject:/home/jai/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jai/myproject/pep_learn/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what happens instead? What are you having problems with, *specifically*?

Comment: Actually I have  search a lot a method to deploy Django without virtualenv but din't get any thing so with my own I tried some hacks but nothing has worked.

Comment: virtualenv isn't relevant or necessary for deployment, it's just a good idea to use it because it makes your code more contained, and easier to upgrade and maintain with time (i.e. if a new Python or Django version is released, you can create a new virtualenv without messing up your existing code). If you have to, just use the globaly installed python instead of the contained one of a virtualenv, otherwise there isn't anything different to do.

Comment: This is great ... but which part of the above .conf file should I remove so that It works with the native installation because removal of this "WSGIDaemonProcess" statement causes fetal error which is responsible  to add python path

Comment: You don't need to remove it. It points at the path for the virtualenv python, so just point it at the path for the system's python instead.

Comment: This is what I did but Its throwing error, Which I forgot what actually it was, I will do it again and post here.